# Not getting entire response from popen

Tags: php, popen, proc-open

Hi I'm running a process with popen;-

```
$handle = popen('python scriptos.py', "r");
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $data = fgets($handle);
    echo "> ".$data;
}
```

And I'm only getting 3 lines from a process that returns 5 lines. I run this exact command in CLi and I will get more response. It's as if it stops reading early (it can take time to complete and updates the next 2 lines whilst working, it's a progress indicator).

Am I doing anything wrong? Is [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) more suitable (i've started seeing if I can try that).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two missing lines are probably being written to [STDERR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29), and `popen()` only returns a pointer for STDOUT.

You can either get a pointer for STDERR using [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), or change the `popen()` line to

```
$handle = popen('python scriptos.py 2>&1', "r");
```

to redirect STDERR to STDOUT, so they are included in your output.

Comment: +1, I too suspect the same, You won't get an EOF until you've read everything.

Comment: Php ... WHAT? ヽ(`Д´)ﾉ︵ ┻━┻